# Couchbase indexes

Tags: performance, couchbase

I have these types of documents in couchbase:

```
{
    delete: true,
    entity: {
        id: "1aec5ee9-bb4b-494d-9cfd-b7d890abad76",
        name: 'Bob'
    }
    _class: "com.company.package.A"
}

{
    delete: false,
    entity: {
        id: "5996c870-3b00-4c6a-a569-52b0c9e8adc9",
        city: 'London'
    }
    _class: "com.company.package.B"
}
```

What indexes would be better for these queries:

```
select * from bucket where _class = "com.company.package.A" and delete=true and entity.name = "Bob"
select * from bucket where _class = "com.company.package.B" and delete=false and entity.city = "London"
```

1. GSI for _class
2. GSI for deleted
3. GSI for entity.name, when _class = "com.company.package.A"
4. GSI for entity.city, when _class = "com.company.package.B"

OR

1. GSI for group of fields {entity.name, _class, deleted}, when _class = "com.company.package.A"
2. GSI for group of fields {entity.city, _class, deleted}, when _class = "com.company.package.B"
3. Do not create separate GSI indexes for _class and deleted at all

Answer (score 0):

A covering Global Secondary Indexes will provide the best performance by eliminating the need to retrieve the documents from the data service.

Use explicit field names when querying. If you use `select *` Couchbase will still have to go to data service to see what other fields were excluded from the index.

In your case you will want two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX covering_index1 ON default(`delete`, entity.id, entity.name) WHERE _class = "com.company.package.A";
CREATE INDEX covering_index2 ON default(`delete`, entity.id, entity.city) WHERE _class = "com.company.package.B";
```

If you don't need `entity.id` you can remove it from the set of covered fields.

Note that `delete` must be in `` ` ``'s because it is a reserved word.